# IE11 and older strips out URL encoding the space character

Tags: php, encoding, character, internet-explorer-11, space

I am using forms on my website, and the form is prepopulated with the recipient depending on who is assigned to the page in the back end (Wordpress).

Anyway on all (decent) browsers the string that is output when I click to the form is eg.

http://(path to my page)/?teacher=Lucy%20Ryder&the_class=Ashtanga%20Yoga%20%E2%80%93%20Lucy%20Class

which works great in displaying my form for me. BUT on Internet Explorer 11 and older, the encoding of the space character is stripped out to get eg this:-

http://(path to my page)/?teacher=Lucy Ryder&the_class=Ashtanga Yoga  Lucy class

- and my page does not display but I get a 'HTTP 400 - the web page cannot be found' message.

Any ideas on how I can make old IE not do this?

Many thanks in advance!